# Issue with Slack bot deployed on Heroku: Multiple Parallel Conversations

Tags: python, heroku, bots, slack, openai-api

I'm developing an intelligent bot for Slack in Python that uses APIs from OpenAI and others services. The bot should process conversations sequentially, ensuring that one conversation is handled completely before starting the next. Conversations consist of multiple stages, such as requesting and then receiving a "challenge" (Message 1), "keywords" (Message 2), etc and also it creates a file for writing the info.

The problem I'm facing is that when I run the application on Heroku, it appears to be generating multiple conversations in parallel from the same Slack chat. For example, when I receive the "challenge" in Message 1, the application seems to treat that input also as "keywords" resulting in the creation of multiple files simultaneously and confusing the conversations.

Interestingly, when I run the application on ngrok, it works perfectly, leading me to suspect that the issue might be related to the way Heroku manages processes in Python.

I've been testing the application with a single dyno on Heroku on a dedicated server, but I haven't been able to resolve this issue yet. There isn't errors on the logs just the messy communication. I'm looking for a solution to ensure that the application processes these conversations sequentially, so that only one conversation is handled at a time. I don't want parallel conversations.

This is the content of my Procfile at the moment:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From [Heroku's documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn#basic-configuration):

> Gunicorn forks multiple system processes within each dyno to allow a Python app to support multiple concurrent requests without requiring them to be thread-safe.

One way to [tell Gunicorn how many workers to use](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-processes) is to set an environment variable called `WEB_CONCURRENCY`, which [Heroku does automatically](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn#basic-configuration):

> The `WEB_CONCURRENCY` environment variable is automatically set by Heroku, based on the processes’ Dyno size. This feature is intended to be a sane starting point for your application. We recommend knowing the memory requirements of your processes and setting this configuration variable accordingly.

If you want to limit your application to one worker*, set the `WEB_CONCURRENCY` [config var](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) (Heroku speak for environment variable) to 1. You can do that [via the dashboard](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-dashboard) or [with the CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-cli):

```
heroku config:set WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
```

---

*A more robust solution would be to update your application code so it doesn't break if there are multiple workers, but that's too large a question to answer here.